# Pull specific data from multidimensional associative array

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => 1
        [count] => 77937
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => 2 
        [count] => 20
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [name] => 4
        [count] => 25
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [name] => 5
        [count] => 11365
    )
)
```

How can I get count for name 3 without looping through the array?

Comment: You can't. Also you have no object in your array with `name===3`

Comment: name === 3 was just an example, I really cant believe there is no way to do this without loops

Comment: Neal is right, there is no such possibility. This data structure does not give you `O(1)` access to such information. One can define and use various approaches here, but all of them will loop "under the hood".

Comment: Well how else ydo you expect to read what the name is equal to?

Comment: What's wrong with loops actually ?

Comment: Without looping or without foreach loop?

Comment: Believe it. You can *change* the data structure to something that uses the name as the key so you can access it directly. But with the current structure you can't.

Comment: Where does this data comes from ? Database ? You could do a SQL query ?

Comment: Problem with loops is the code is for a massive reports and I will prob end up with close to 50 loops, The data comes from an external party, the name does not have to be int it could be store1

Comment: But 50 loops is nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Index once, read often:

```
$indexed = array();

foreach ($arr as $values) {
    $indexed[$values['name']] = $values;
}

echo $indexed[3]['count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5.5, you can use `array_column`:

```
$index = array_column($arr, 'count', 'name');
echo $index[3];
```

You can actually do that with one line:

```
echo array_column($arr, 'count', 'name')[3];
```

Other than that, a loop is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$p = array(array('name' => 1, 'count' => 77937),
           array('name' => 2, 'count' => 20),
           2 => array('name' => 4, 'count' => 25),
           3 => array('name' => 5, 'count' => 11365));

class my_finder
{
    private $n;
    function __construct($n)
    {
        $this->n = $n;
    }
    function findByName($arr)
    {
        return $arr['name'] == $this->n;
    }
}

$matches = array_filter($p, array(new my_finder(4), 'findByName'));

print_r ($matches);
```

Of course, this only **pretends** that there's no loop. array_filter iterates through the array for you anyway.

Comment: This convoluted way is of course only necessary before PHP 5.3, where anonymous functions became available...

Comment: ok... but how can I pass an additional parameter to anonymous function (the 'name' in this case)? Could You provide some code?

Comment: You don't really need to, since you're writing the function inline anyway. But you can `use` surrounding variables: `array_filter($p, function ($p) use ($i) { return $p[$i] == 4; })`

Answer (score -2):

try this,   I have selected 2 for name field in function...

```
<?php
global $count;

$temp = array( 
 '0' => array ( 'name' => 1, 'count' => 77937 ),
 '1' => array ( 'name' => 2 ,'count' => 20 ),
 '2' => array ( 'name' => 4 ,'count' => 25 ),
 '3' => array ( 'name' => 5, 'count' => 11365)
 );

function mapper($data)
{
 global $count;

  if($data['name'] == 2)
  $count = $data['count'];
}

 array_map('mapper',$temp);

 echo $count;
```

Comment: I would like to hear reason for the down vote.

Comment: I do not know the reason for the down vote, but your approach is not the answer, as the author is looking for a loop-free method, array_map is looping over elements, it does not matter that there is no "for" keyword :)

Comment: yet another answer with a foreach is upvoted...